# Cart throb only allow one item on checkout

Tags: cartthrob

In Cartthrob I would like to only allow the user to purchase one product on checkout. If a new product is added to the cart it replaces the one already in the cart. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I work at Vector Media Group; we make CartThrob).

Depending on your site and product setup, you may be able to do this by using a `clear_cart` tag followed by an `add_to_cart` tag. These may be able to be on the same template, which you send a person to to add to your cart, or have the empty redirect to the add. This method won't work for products where you need to pass around options and such though.

The more reliable method that would let you handle more complexity is a simple extension that fires on `add_to_cart`. It can remove the old product when the new one is added. Feel free to contact us if you need help making that!

Comment: Hey Matt, in my case using the clear_cart tag on the same page as the add_to_cart form is working. Thanks for your help!